# reactive_flutter_BLE - app finds device but cannot connect (and read BLE data)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

First code, which compiles, but does not work as expected:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';


class BluetoothConnectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BluetoothConnectionScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BluetoothConnectionScreen> createState() => _BluetoothConnectionScreenState();
}

class _BluetoothConnectionScreenState extends State<BluetoothConnectionScreen> {

  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();

  late DiscoveredDevice _myDevice;

  late StreamSubscription<DiscoveredDevice> _scanStream;
  late QualifiedCharacteristic _rxCharacteristic;

  final Uuid serviceUuid = Uuid.parse("4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b");
  final Uuid characteristicUuid = Uuid.parse("beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8");

  late List<int> _infoCharacteristics;

  bool _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = false;
  bool _scanStarted = false;
  bool _connected = false;

  void _startScan() async {
    bool permGranted = false;
    setState(() {
      _scanStarted = true;
    });

    PermissionStatus permission;
    permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
    if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) permGranted = true;

    if (permGranted) {
      _scanStream = flutterReactiveBle
          .scanForDevices(withServices: [serviceUuid]).listen((device) {
        if (device.name.startsWith("L")) {
          setState(() {
            _myDevice = device;
            _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = true;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void _connectToDevice() {

    _scanStream.cancel();

    Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> _currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToAdvertisingDevice(
        id: _myDevice.id,
        prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        withServices: [serviceUuid, characteristicUuid]);
    _currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {
      switch (event.connectionState) {
        case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          {
            _rxCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
                serviceId: serviceUuid,
                characteristicId: characteristicUuid,
                deviceId: event.deviceId);
            setState(() {
              _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = false;
              _connected = true;
            });
            break;
          }

        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          {
            setState(() {
              _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = true;
              _connected = false;
            });
            break;
          }
        default:
      }
    });
  }

  void _readFromDevice() async
  {
    if (_connected) {
    setState(() async {
      _infoCharacteristics.addAll(await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(_rxCharacteristic));
    });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _infoCharacteristics.addAll([1,2,3]);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("BLE"),
    ),
    body: SafeArea(child:
    Center(child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text("Started scan: $_scanStarted"),
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.bluetooth,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          size: 24.0,
        ),
        onPressed: () => _startScan(),
        label: const Text("Find and pair BLE device"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          fixedSize: const Size(
            290,
            32,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text("Device found? $_foundDeviceWaitingToConnect"),
      Text("Scan started? $_scanStarted"),
      Text("Connected? $_connected"),
      _connected ? Text("OK! Device name: ${_myDevice.id.toString()}") : Text("Device not connected!"),
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.bluetooth,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          size: 24.0,
        ),
        onPressed: () => _connectToDevice,
        label: const Text("Connect to BLE device"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          fixedSize: const Size(
            290,
            32,
          ),
        ),
      ),
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.bluetooth,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            size: 24.0,
          ),
          onPressed: () => _readFromDevice,
          label: const Text("Read information"),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            fixedSize: const Size(
              290,
              32,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        _connected ? Text("OK ! $_infoCharacteristics") : Text("Device not connected!"),
    ],

    ))));
  }
}
```

My Flutter app compiles, but does not work properly. It finds device by UUID, but cannot connect to it. Don't know why. Finally I want to read characteristics from my device (text represented by strings). Any advice is welcome!. Thx.

I added all needed app permissions (in Android Manifest file), and this app have granted all needed permissions in Android OS 11. Of course I have tested it on real device, mobile phone.

What should I do?

---

LOGCAT logs:

2023-04-28 22:15:17.784 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.784 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #0   _BluetoothConnectionScreenState._startScan (package:my_app/Screens/BluetoothConnection/BluetoothPairingScreen.dart:38:12)[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.784 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #1   _BluetoothConnectionScreenState.build. (package:my_app/Screens/BluetoothConnection/BluetoothPairingScreen.dart:128:26)[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.784 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.785 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│  Device scan started[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.785 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #0   _BluetoothConnectionScreenState._startScan (package:my_app/Screens/BluetoothConnection/BluetoothPairingScreen.dart:49:14)[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #1   [0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│  Permisssion granted[0m
2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #0   _BluetoothConnectionScreenState._startScan (package:my_app/Screens/BluetoothConnection/BluetoothPairingScreen.dart:61:12)[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│ #1   [0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m│  Device found: false[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.797 10350-16111 flutter                 com.example.my_app       I  [38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m

2023-04-28 22:15:17.799 10350-16177 BluetoothAdapter        com.example.my_app       D  isLeEnabled(): ON

2023-04-28 22:15:17.810 10350-16177 BluetoothAdapter        com.example.my_app       D  isLeEnabled(): ON

2023-04-28 22:15:17.812 10350-16191 BluetoothLeScanner      com.example.my_app       D  onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=10 mScannerId=0

2023-04-28 22:15:17.815  2029-7327  AppOps                  pid-2029                             E  Bad call made by uid 1002. Package "com.example.my_app" does not belong to uid 1002.

[image]

Using @rrttrr code (method below) I got logs:

W/FinalizerDaemon(15204): type=1400 audit(0.0:2118): avc: denied { getopt } for path="/dev/socket/usap_pool_primary" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c223,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.my_app

D/BluetoothGatt(15204): connect() - device: 54:43:B2:46:84:F6, auto: false, eattSupport: false

D/BluetoothGatt(15204): registerApp()

D/BluetoothGatt(15204): registerApp() - UUID=0243bb19-1462-46bb-a2ab-e636e81b812f

I/flutter (15204): BLE connection state: DeviceConnectionState.connecting

I/flutter (15204): BLE connection state: DeviceConnectionState.connecting

I/flutter (15204): BLE connection state: DeviceConnectionState.disconnected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these:

1. Verify that
   you are able to connect to your BLE device using a third-party app
   like nRF Connect. Ensure that the UUIDs you are using
   to connect are correct and that the device is advertising and
   discoverable.
2. If you are having issues with `connectToAdvertisingDevice`, try using
   `connectToDevice` instead. `connectToAdvertisingDevice` works only when
   the BLE device is advertising. `connectToDevice` will attempt
   to connect to the device regardless of whether it's advertising or
   not.
3. Keep an eye on the logs while you're testing your app. Sometimes,
   the BLE device may disconnect soon after connecting. If you notice that the device has disconnected, try
   reconnecting again. You may need to implement some logic in your app
   to automatically reconnect in case of a disconnect.

You can try connecting directly using the below method to see if it's working. It will print the connection state and error if any.

```
  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate>? deviceConnection;

  void connectToBleDevice() async {
    await deviceConnection?.cancel();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    deviceConnection = flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToDevice(
      id: DEVICE_MAC_ID,
      servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {
        Uuid.parse(SERVICE_UUID): [
          Uuid.parse(CHAR_UUID_1),
          Uuid.parse(CHAR_UUID_2),
        ]
      },
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )
        .listen((connectionState) async {
      debugPrint("BLE connection state: " +
          connectionState.connectionState.toString());
    }, onError: (dynamic error) async {
      debugPrint("BLE connection error: ${error.toString()}");
    });
  }
```

Comment: I will try all Your advices and come back here as soon as possible. Thx.

Comment: 1) Already checked, and with nRF device works fine. I can read characteristics. 2) I have tried - have not helped. 3) I must try, but to be honest don't know how to read logs on real device. Should I have it connected to Android Studio via cable??

Comment: You can also try to connect directly using the device UUID you got from nRF Connect, to check whether you are able to connect that way. 3) Yes, connect to a physical device and install the app via IDE.

Comment: I know the exact UUID of device and of service. I have managed to use phone via cable. I am updating my post with logcat logs...

Comment: I posted a method, you can try connecting using that and check the logs.

Comment: Also, look at the "Run" tab too for logs.

Comment: I used provided code. Thx for time and effort! I have edited post and put logs I got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253371/discussion-between-rrttrr-and-prertoquebas).